# How to set variable in procmail as To email address

Tags: procmail

I have a Procmail rule that uses `formail` to parse the `To:` email header to determine the email address the email was sent to:

```
TO_=`formail -XTo:`
```

This isn't working, as I'd like `${TO_}` to evaluate to "address@domain.com", but what I'm getting is "To: firstName lastName".

How can I set an environment variable in a procmail script to the format I'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are extracting the full contents of the `To:` header, which should normally look something like `To: Real Name <recipient@example.net>`. There are many variations, though; it could also be `recipient@example.net (Real Name)`, for example, though this format is obsolescent.

Demo:

```
bash$ cat <<\: >nst.rc
SHELL=/bin/sh
TO_=`formail -XTo:`
:

bash$ cat <<\: >nst.eml
From: me <sender@example.org>
To: Real Name <recipient@example.net>
Subject: All your base

They are belong to us
:

bash$ procmail -m VERBOSE=yes DEFAULT=/dev/null nst.rc <nst.eml
procmail: [271] Fri Sep  2 10:01:29 2022
procmail: Assigning "DEFAULT=/dev/null"
procmail: Assigning "MAILDIR=."
procmail: Rcfile: "nst.rc"
procmail: Assigning "SHELL=/bin/sh"
procmail: Executing "formail,-XTo:"
procmail: Assigning "TO_=To: Real Name <recipient@example.net>"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/dev/null"
procmail: Opening "/dev/null"
 Subject: All your base
  Folder: /dev/null                             114
```

If you know that the header contains the address between `<brokets>`, you can extract the text between them without using `formail` or another external utility.

```
:0
* ^To:.*<\/[^>]+
{ TO_=$MATCH }
```

This uses Procmail's special `\/` extraction token which assigns the matching text after it into the special internal variable `MATCH`.

```
bash$ cat <<\: >nst2.rc
SHELL=/bin/sh

:0
* ^To:.*<\/[^>]+
{ TO_=$MATCH }
:

bash$ procmail -m VERBOSE=yes DEFAULT=/dev/null nst2.rc <nst.eml
procmail: [275] Fri Sep  2 10:03:26 2022
procmail: Assigning "DEFAULT=/dev/null"
procmail: Assigning "MAILDIR=."
procmail: Rcfile: "nst2.rc"
procmail: Assigning "SHELL=/bin/sh"
procmail: Assigning "MATCH="
procmail: Matched "recipient@example.net"
procmail: Match on "^To:.*<\/[^>]+"
procmail: Assigning "TO_=recipient@example.net"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/dev/null"
procmail: Opening "/dev/null"
 Subject: All your base
  Folder: /dev/null                             114
```

Tangentially, if you wanted to extract a header *value* without the header keyword itself, that would be

```
formail -zxTo:
```

with a lowercase `-x`.

But this still extracts the entire value, i.e. `Real Name <recipient@example.net>`. You could of course add a simple `sed` script to extract just the email terminus; but generally speaking, you want to avoid spawning external processes for efficiency reasons.